# Create a unique name for the uploaded image

Tags: php

I have a certain code for image upload .I found this on the internet and there was no explanation of the code either.What i can understand from the code is that php upload a certain file makes it a temporary file and then moves the temporary file to the original location

Code Looks something like this

```
 $filename = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
          list($width, $height) = getimagesize( $filename );


          move_uploaded_file($filename,  $imagePath . $_FILES["img"]["name"]);
```

What happens now is that when i try to provide an unique name to the image when it is being moved using the `move_uploaded_file` then a file does come up inside the folder but it says an invalid file and with the extension type of `file`.
My code for trying to achieve the same but with an unique name/id for the uploaded image.

```
$uniquesavename=time().uniqid(rand());
$filename = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
      list($width, $height) = getimagesize( $filename );
      move_uploaded_file($filename,  $imagePath . $uniquesavename);
```

How to achieve the same as before and could you please explain me the previous code as well?

Comment: you need to add the extension

Comment: a solution for get unique names is add timestamp to the name

Comment: @Mihai thanks.That worked.Could you explain the code as welll?

Comment: @stig-js whaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaat?

Comment: @stig-js Didn't `time()` does the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Sample code:**

```
// Get file path from post data by using $_FILES
$filename = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
// Make sure that it's a valid image which can get width and height
list($width, $height) = getimagesize( $filename );
// Call php function move_uploaded_file to move uploaded file
move_uploaded_file($filename,  $imagePath . $_FILES["img"]["name"]);
```

Please try this one:

```
// Make sure this imagePath is end with slash
$imagePath = '/root/path/to/image/folder/';
$uniquesavename=time().uniqid(rand());
$destFile = $imagePath . $uniquesavename . '.jpg';
$filename = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
list($width, $height) = getimagesize( $filename );       
move_uploaded_file($filename,  $destFile);
```

**Edit 1:**
To get image type in two ways:

- Get the file type from upload file name.
- Use php function as below

### CODE

```
// Get details of image
list($width, $height, $typeCode) = getimagesize($filename);
$imageType = ($typeCode == 1 ? "gif" : ($typeCode == 2 ? "jpeg" : ($typeCode == 3 ? "png" : FALSE)));
```

Comment: What if the original file is not jpg?Get the original file`s extension instead.

Comment: @Mihai yeah extension can be get using something like this `$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["img"]["name"]);
 $extension = end($temp);`

Comment: @BobGao update the answer that don't just use `.jpg` but something more general .I will accept it as correct .Would be helpful for other OP.Use my function if you want to .

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Yes, you can take a look from this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php, uniqid returns a unique identifier, and we append with timestamp, so it's very low probability to generate two same IDs.

Comment: We are not sure as you said `so it's very low probability to generate two same IDs` two ids may be same;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 ahah, right, everything is possible, but in this case, the chance could be considered as O, you can Imagine that at a same time two files uploaded and function uniqid returns the exactly same ID twice, I think you won't see this scenario in your life, if so, it's time to buy lottery:)

Answer (score 4):

```
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmp_name =  $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$location = "uploads/";
$new_name = $location.time()."-".rand(1000, 9999)."-".$name;
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $new_name)){
            echo "uploaded";
}
else{
    sleep(rand(1,5));
    $new_name = $location.time()."-".rand(1000, 9999)."-".$name;
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $new_name)){
            echo "uploaded";
    }
    else{
            echo"failed, better luck next time";
    }
}
```

here, location is folder inside directory, i mainly create folder "uploads"
time() adds timestamp , which is always unique, until two person upload at same time, which is rare.

moreover, adding 4 digit random number to it , making combination rarest

after that adding actual file name , to making combination unique.

why i use it :

1. u can extract timestamp later if u need to know when image was uploaded.
2. u can extract actual filename too.

Lets, say our so unique combination somehow fails,
then, php instance will wait for 1 to 5 second whatever random number is generated. and rename with latest timestamp and regenerated random number.

It's the best u can think of without being resource hog.

Comment: Nope when this method used on a large website that involves heavy users can show the same name as at certain time many user might be uploading images and that would end up using the same name because the timestamp is same.So saying timestamp is always unique, is wrong.

Comment: lol lol, read whole code , 4 digit random number which u can increase to 6 or whatever, and then a else on fail with new timestamp

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
$strtotime = strtotime("now");
$filename = $strtotime.'_'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
```